# Swift 1.2 Upgradation

Tags: ios, swift, build-settings, xcode6.3.2

I have updated my Swift project to version 1.2 and the build times have been improved after using **Build Setting** option Whole Module Optimization=Yes. But even if there is a small change in Swift file the entire Objective C files are getting compiled when I tried to build. Is there any other optimization option Available? I'm using Xcode 6.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you only enable Whole Module Optimization in your Release build and leave it off for Debug. That way you won't have to wait long for compilation and testing builds but your users still get the benefit of the speeds of Whole Module Optimization.

Comment: I have made the change still there is a bit delay if i make a change in a single swift file.